# Scala - What is the difference between size and length of a Seq?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, seq

What is the difference between size and length of a Seq? When to use one and when the other?

```
scala> var a :Seq[String] = Seq("one", "two")
a: Seq[String] = List(one, two)

scala> a.size
res6: Int = 2

scala> a.length
res7: Int = 2
```

It's the same?

Thanks

Comment: As you may have seen in scaladoc, [they are the same](http://take.ms/smt8V)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Nothing. In the [Seq doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.Seq), at the size method it is clearly stated: "The size of this sequence, equivalent to `length`.".

Comment: I guess I'm the only one who cares, but why?

Comment: Maybe some legacy libraries used size, others used length, so they kept both not to bother having to change one or the other? Wild guess.

Answer (score 75):

`size` is defined in `GenTraversableOnce`, whereas `length` is defined in `GenSeqLike`, so `length` only exists for `Seq`s, whereas `size` exists for all `Traversable`s. For `Seq`s, however, as was already pointed out, `size` simply delegates to `length` (which probably means that, after inlining, you will get identical bytecode).

Answer (score 14):

In a Seq they are the same, as others have mentioned. However, for information, this is what IntelliJ warns on a `scala.Array`:

> Replace .size with .length on arrays and strings
>
> Inspection info: This
>   inspection reports array.size and string.size calls. While such calls
>   are legitimate, they require an additional implicit conversion to
>   SeqLike to be made. A common use case would be calling length on
>   arrays and strings may provide significant advantages.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing, one delegates to the other. See SeqLike trait.

```
  /** The size of this $coll, equivalent to `length`.
   *
   *  $willNotTerminateInf
   */
  override def size = length
```

Answer (score 7):

I did an experiment, using Scala version 2.12.8, and a million item list. Upon the first use, length() is 7 or 8 times faster than size(). But on the 2nd try on the same list, size() is about the same speed as length().

However, after some time, presumably the cache is gone, size() is slow() by 7 or 8 times again.

This shows that length() is preferred for sequences. It's not just another name for size().