# How to count number of columns in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe in Spark I want to count the number of available columns in it. I know how to count the number of rows in column but I want to count number of columns.

```
val df1 = Seq(
    ("spark", "scala",  "2015-10-14", 10,"rahul"),
    ("spark", "scala", "2015-10-15", 11,"abhishek"),
    ("spark", "scala", "2015-10-16", 12,"Jay"),
    ("spark","scala",null,13,"Kiran"))
  .toDF("bu_name","client_name","date","patient_id","paitent _name")
df1.show
```

Can anybody tell me how I can count number of column count in this dataframe? I am using the Scala language.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To count the number of columns, simply do:

```
df1.columns.size
```

Comment: Or df1.columns.length, seems to be faster

Comment: @JohannGoulley: They should be equivalent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966705/scala-what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-length-of-a-seq

Answer (score 10):

In python, the following code worked for me:

```
print(len(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 5):

data.columns accesses the list of column titles. All you have to do is count the number of items in the list. so

```
len(df1.columns)
```

works
To obtain the whole data in a single variable, we do

```
rows = df.count()
columns = len(df.columns)
size = (rows, columns)
print(size)
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of the mutable indexed sequence also work.

```
df.columns.length
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the columns of a Spark dataFrame:

```
len(df1.columns)
```

and to count the number of rows of a dataFrame:

```
df1.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

in Pyspark you can just `result.select("your column").count()`